# Are there everyday materials that change color, depending on illumination spectrum?

Tags: optics, visible-light, education, home-experiment, optical-materials

Initially I wanted to ask [this exact question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518495/) about color change due to "white" light source spectrum change, and the accepted answer satisfies me fully.

However the answer says that most of objects have "rarely a nice clean notch" in the reflectance spectrum. But I wonder where I can find a list of accessible materials, that could create such mind-boggling effect.

I want to make a scientific show for kids, and my goal is to explode their brains.

Comment: You don't mean smth like a sheet of white paper, that looks different when illuminated differently (green when illuminated with green, red when with red, etc)?

Comment: A solution of holmium chloride changes color dramatically when switching between daylight and fluorescent lamp lighting. Look up holmium oxide in wikipedia to see the color change: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmium%28III%29_oxide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it.

There are certain semi-precious gemstones which, when illuminated with a certain color of incident light, appear a *different color* from the incident color- or from their color when illuminated with full-spectrum light. When I remember the name of the stone I will edit this response, but it IS mind-blowing! See https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS746US748&lei=5YXHY6XVIvza0PEPs-Ck0A0&q=list%20of%20color%20changing%20gemstones&ved=2ahUKEwjl2-jWs9D8AhV8LTQIHTMwCdoQsKwBKAF6BAh-EAI.